# Numpy function for iteration over an array with access to rows & colums

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

With which inbuilt numpy functions (due to performance issues) I could iterate through an array with access to row and column numbers and element data as if I was using loop like

```
dims=array.shape
for i in range (dims[0]):
    for j in range (dims[1]):
        ...
```

for purpose of getting standard deviation of covariance matrix.

Comment: There is no function that would allow you to iterate a numpy array without performance loss. Numpy is great to perform algebraic operations or simple aritmethic operations, and has tons of features such as fancy indexing, masking, broadcasting, etc.. But if you really really need to iterate a numpy array, you are screwed. Your best option would be to write a C/C++/Cython/CUDA extension and wrap it from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like that you are looking for `numpy.nditer`. Here is the example of code:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array(
  [
    [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
    [ 8.,  9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
    [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.]
  ]
)

it = np.nditer(array, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
  print(it[0], it.multi_index)
  it.iternext()
```

In this example you will recieve folowing output:

```
0.0 (0, 0)
1.0 (0, 1)
2.0 (0, 2)
3.0 (0, 3)
4.0 (0, 4)
5.0 (0, 5)
6.0 (0, 6)
7.0 (0, 7)
8.0 (1, 0)
9.0 (1, 1)
10.0 (1, 2)
11.0 (1, 3)
12.0 (1, 4)
13.0 (1, 5)
14.0 (1, 6)
15.0 (1, 7)
16.0 (2, 0)
17.0 (2, 1)
18.0 (2, 2)
19.0 (2, 3)
20.0 (2, 4)
21.0 (2, 5)
22.0 (2, 6)
23.0 (2, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked out, although I'm not sure about any serious performance gain.

Comment: @TimM. check [this](https://repl.it/MA9J). It looks like double iteration is more effective than `numpy.nditer`

Comment: Also, if you are using python2 - use xrange instead of range

Comment: @TimM. `np.nditer` is most useful as a stepping stone toward porting the code to `cython`, as illustrated in  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html (read through to the end).

Comment: xrange has indeed sped iteration up, although not much.